# Python Graphics library for basic 2D graphics (architectural)?

Tags: product

I used to write a lot of Python code, but never used it to output any graphics, outside of plots for data analysis.

I now work for a construction company that is beginning to manufacture and sell windows and doors. As a little passion project, I fancied writing a programme that could output basic reports for customer quotes, mainly for my own amusement. Commonly, other manufacturers use software that outputs a sketch of the window or door, based on dimensions and product type. I’m wondering if anyone could recommend a Python graphics library I could leverage to do something similar?